# Why does accept() block, when listen() is the very first involved in TCP?

Tags: linux, sockets, tcp, listen

The `accept()` blocks, until another connection is made and the return the sockfd the can communicate both sides on. But why is it `accept()` that blocks, when the first thing that is done is the three way handshake. And the handshake is *not* done by `accept()`, but by `listen()`. So I would expect to `listen()` block rather then `accept()`, since it is firstly involved in TCP. I know the kernel does some queuing of the incoming connections, but still the very first function involved in is `listen()`, then the connection is moved forward in the queue to `accept()`. So when I do first connection, `listen()` will do the 3whs, and the server blocks in `accept()`. So another connection cannot do another 3whs, becuase the server does no go *back* to `listen()`, which does the 3whs? Or why does `accept()` blocks and not `listen()`?

Comment: @Carcigenicate i did not say anything about changing the behaviour of the `listen()` function (so it *would not* return `connfd` as `accept()`), it would just process the connection down to `accept()` as normally. But accept() is not the very first function involved in TCP as listen() is. That does not make sense to me

Comment: As I said, the listen would block, new connection arrived, 2whs is done, the process will follow with accept(). The functionality is the same as it is now, but the first encounter with the new connection would be listen instead of accept, since accept does *not* perform 3whs. So in current model, it does not make sense for me, because if accept blocs, new connection cannot do 3whs since that does listen and not accept

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`listen()` and `accept()` are two completely different operations.  Yourr understanding of how they work is incorrect.

`listen()` merely sets up the listening socket's backlog and opens the bound port, so clients can start connecting to the socket.  That opening is a very quick operation, there is no need to worry about it blocking.

A 3-way handshake is not performed by `listen()`.  It is performed by the kernel when a client tries to connect to the opened port and gets placed into the listening socket's backlog.  Each new client connection performs its own 3-way handshake.

Once a client connection is fully handshaked, that connection is made available for `accept()` to extract it from the backlog.  `accept()` blocks (or, if you use a non-blocking listening socket, `accept()` succeeds) only when a new client connection is available for subsequent communication.

You call `listen()` only 1 time, to open the listening port, that is all it does.  Then you have to call `accept()` for each client that you want to communicate with.  That is why `accept()` blocks and `listen()` does not.

Comment: If kernel does the 3whs, then when? Is it done between the calls to listen and accept, or while accept, or when?

Comment: The kernel can do 2whs anytime the port is open? which it is after listen?

Comment: Yes, the 3-way handshake can be performed at any time after `listen()` exits. But how the handshake is managed depends on the kernel. When a new connection arrives, some kernels complete the 3-way handshake immediately and put the connection into a separate queue for `accept()` to pull from. Some kernels only perform a partial handshake and then finish it only when `accept()` is actually called.

Comment: But, you don't really need to concern yourself with those details, the kernel handles them for you. All you need to concern yourself with is calling `listen()` to open the chosen port, and calling `accept()` to receive connections from it. The rest is handled behind the scenes for you. If you don't want `accept()` blocking your code, move it to a worker thread, or use a non-blocking listening socket.

Comment: This is not answer of the timing of the 3whs. You said it does kernel, but you yourself do not know when it does it

Comment: The timing is *implementation-specific* in the kernel, but no matter *when* it is handled, it is handled entirely by the kernel, and it is still handled AFTER `listen()` exits and BEFORE `accept()` exits.  Why do you care WHEN the handshake is performed? It is not in your control.

Comment: The reason is that I cannot control it, but I rely on it -> In select() call, if I am checking it the listening fd (after listen() of course) is "readable" only after that I can call accept(). So the "readability" with "listening socket" I consider the 3whs the kernel does, but you can see here that `listen()` *does* change the state for select, but **not** the accept().

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/227230/discussion-between-remy-lebeau-and-milanhrabos).